# What is the word for "doing something in various steps"?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

The expression I am looking for is something like this:

> Rather than putting the whole mixture of spices at one while cooking something, put a part of it in various **steps/rounds** separated by a regular interval.

Is using *rounds* correct, or should I use something else?

Basically, what I want to know is what word I am supposed to use to mean I am doing something in distributed steps rather than all at once.

Answer (score 3):

Your original sentence is unclear to this extent: Do you mean that each spice should be put in separately (one spice at a time) or that they should all be mixed together into something like a curry powder and then added in equal fractional parts?

I'll assume the former (it's more rational for cooking for a couple of reasons).

You can say it this way:

> Rather than adding all (of) the spices at the same time while cooking something, **put them in one at a time at regular intervals,** for example, every 2 minutes.

You can also say:

> ... **put them in (separately) step by step,** ..."

There's no need to clutter the sentence with unnecessary terms like "rounds" and "steps".

Comment: Actually it is latter, what I want to know is that, if I am doing something repetitive like reading a particular chapter of a book but not doing at once, but doing it in several steps, what will I call that,

Comment: @johnmconore -  Reading a book - "you are reading it in *parts*"?

Comment: yeah, not reading it all at once, reading some part today some tomorrow some over the weekend. Hope this helps

Comment: @johnmc: You can say that you're reading the book "chapter by chapter", "a few pages at a time", "piecemeal", "in 15-minute chunks": whatever best describes what you're actually doing. A more general description might be "in {manageable / digestible / bearable} parts". You can read a play or a screenplay "scene by scene", a textbook "chapter by chapter" or "topic by topic", etc. We don't have a more general description, except, perhaps, "part by part" or "a little at a time".

Comment: @johnmconore If you need to be exceptionally pompous - if an editor or professor presses for a more formal expression - you may say "incrementally" or "in increments of [quantity]". But try to resist.

Answer (score 1):

A typical way of saying this is *I followed the recipe step by step*, or *I followed the steps in order*.

I don't know a good single word for the process, although *gradually*, used in context, comes close.  It still needs a verb to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

"Incrementally" means "do things in steps".

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a common noun that comes to mind that means this, but several adjectives.

*Periodically* or *gradually* probably expresses what you mean the most succinctly:

> Rather than putting the whole mixture of spices in at once while cooking something, periodically add part of the mixture while it cooks.

---

*Rounds* or *steps* refer to a process, not a thing.

The first thing that comes to my mind with the word *round* is a game of some sort.  A situation where there are multiple people (or other entities) and everyone/each thing is taking/receiving a "turn".  There is an implication that everyone gets a turn, but no implication on the time that may take.  You only have a single thing (the dish) receiving a single action (adding spices) that is desired on a defined time frame so the word *round* is not suitable.

*Steps* means distinct actions to take to accomplish something.  It does not by default suggest a single repeated action over time, but rather various different actions that must be completed in sequence.  So in my opinion this word is not entirely suitable either.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would say:

> Put the spices in **over time**, while you're cooking.

Answer (score -1):

This is a stuffy term, but "seriatim" might do it if all else fails.
   "...seriatim is one after another, in order; taking one topic or subject at a time in an order; sequentially." - Wikidiff

Comment: Is "seristum" used anywhere outside of legal proceedings?

Answer (score -2):

"Rather than putting the whole mixture of spices at one while cooking something, add it in several batches."